# How can I reduce the reference line for widgets in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a project with more than 50 plus layouts, for each one I am doing codes for getting the reference of the widgets like findViewById. Is there anyway to reduce the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use [Butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife).

Because it uses annotation processing during compilation, there is no performance/overhead penalty during a runtime.

As a tip, don't forget put `ButterKnife.inject(this);` in a proper place like `onCreate()`

Answer (score 3):

Android introduced `Data Binding Library` to get rid of `findViewById();` visit [Android Official : Data Binding Guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html). 
**Important  :**  Its in Beta Version.

**Updated**:
Now its available in [Alpha](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)